# MobaXTerm : How to change mouse scroll in to terminal screen scroll up/down?

Tags: terminal, mouse, mobaxterm

The default behavior is history commands scrolling.
Any way to change it?

Answer (score 7):

I believe if you hold Shift down it will scroll the output and not simply cycle through command history.

Comment: If you're not sure, you should leave a comment for OP to verify. If it turns out to be helpful you can leave a full answer for OP to accept.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a default behaviour and cannot be configured using the UI / settings dialogue. You have to manually edit the ini-file.

1. Close MobaXTerm, otherwise changes to the ini-file will be overwritten
2. find the documents inside your user folder and got to the folder named **MobaXterm**
3. open the file named **MobaXterm.ini** with a text editor
4. look for the section called **[Misc]**
5. in this section add a line like this:

   ScrollMod=alt

Chosse a parameter that suits your needs: alt | ctrl | shift

6. open MobXTerm again and scroll the window holding down the selected control key

see MobaXTerm-documentation here:
https://blog.mobatek.net/post/mobaxterm-configuration-settings/

But heads up. This will probably still cause problems inside a screen session. You can fix this quick by pressing **Ctrl + A and Esc** or edit your .screenrc [as described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18006/can-mouse-wheel-scrolling-work-in-a-screen-session):

> termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@ In tmux, it'd be something like
>   (.tmux.conf):
>
> set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'

Comment: Works well, but not in tmux